# How to access 1 cell in a DataFrame that has a Float64 as index? (Python3)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Newbie here, I have csv file with rows that I want to index by a UNIQUE float

```
"GOOGL @ 759.28"
"August 19 2016 Calls","","","","","","","","","","August 19 2016 Puts"
,"IV","Delta","Open Int","Vol","Change","Last","Bid","Ask","Strike","Bid","Ask","Last","Change","Vol","Open Int","Delta","IV"
,"85.67","0.971","1","0","0.00","233.45","257.30","261.60","500.00","0.00","3.60","0.05","0.00","0","2","-0.025","83.12"
,"83.91","0.971","0","0","0.00","0.00","252.20","256.60","505.00","0.00","0.50","0.00","0.00","0","0","-0.006","61.19"
,"82.16","0.970","0","0","0.00","0.00","247.30","251.60","510.00","0.00","4.00","0.81","0.00","0","1","-0.028","81.24"
,"46.25","0.999","0","0","0.00","0.00","242.30","246.70","515.00","0.00","0.55","0.00","0.00","0","0","-0.007","59.20"
,"44.85","0.999","0","0","0.00","0.00","237.40","241.60","520.00","0.05","0.60","0.13","0.00","0","11","-0.008","59.08"
,"43.47","0.999","0","0","0.00","0.00","232.40","236.60","525.00","0.00","0.60","0.00","0.00","0","0","-0.007","57.16"
,"42.08","0.999","0","0","0.00","0.00","227.40","231.60","530.00","0.00","0.65","0.10","0.00","0","18","-0.008","56.41"
```

My code:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/python

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import locale

locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8' )

def read_csv_file(pathToFile="options.csv"):
    return  pd.read_csv(pathToFile, header=2,
                              dtype={"Strike":np.float}, index_col="Strike",
                              usecols=["Strike","Bid","Ask","Bid.1","Ask.1"],
                              thousands=',').reset_index()


def list_record_with_strike(strike, df):
    for index, longCall in df.iterrows():
      if strike == np.float(longCall['Strike']) :
        print("Ask Price of strike: ", longCall['Strike'], "is  ",longCall['Ask'])


def get_record_by_strike(strike, df ):
    print(df[strike])

def main():
    # data frame
    df = read_csv_file()
    list_record_with_strike(510,df)
    get_record_by_strike(510,df)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get this output:

```
> Ask Price of strike:  510.0 is  251.6 Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File "spikes/OptionsReader.py", line 32, in <module>
>     main()   File "spikes/OptionsReader.py", line 29, in main
>     get_record_by_strike(510,df)   File "spikes/OptionsReader.py", line 23, in get_record_by_strike
>     print(df[strike])   File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line
> 1969, in __getitem__
>     return self._getitem_column(key)   File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line
> 1976, in _getitem_column
>     return self._get_item_cache(key)   File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line
> 1091, in _get_item_cache
>     values = self._data.get(item)   File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py",
> line 3211, in get
>     loc = self.items.get_loc(item)   File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line
> 1759, in get_loc
>     return self._engine.get_loc(key)   File "pandas/index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3979)   File
> "pandas/index.pyx", line 157, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
> (pandas/index.c:3843)   File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 668, in
> pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12265)
> File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 676, in
> pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12216)
> KeyError: 510
```

Now, I know that I can get one series because of the list_record_with_strike correctly locates it. (but I goes through the full thing) but for some reason (I think trivial, but unknown to me) I cannot get the record directly by its index...

Comment: Thanks @Levon for the editing, Really appreciated

Comment: Can you include the output of `df.dtypes` so we can see how the dataframe is constructed? Also, you're passing `510`, which is an integer. Could you try passing `510.` to see if that works?

Comment: Hello, I used 510.0 and nothing... Adding a print(df['Strike']) in the main method after creating df.  printed this \n ' 142     960.0
143     970.0
144     980.0
145     990.0
146    1000.0
Name: Strike, type: float64´

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def read_csv_file(pathToFile="options.csv"):
    return  pd.read_csv(pathToFile, header=2,
                        dtype={"Strike":np.float}, index_col="Strike",
                        usecols=["Strike","Bid","Ask","Bid.1","Ask.1"],
                        thousands=',').reset_index()


def list_record_with_strike(strike, df):
    for i, (index, longCall) in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
        if strike == np.float(longCall['Strike']) :
            print("Ask Price of strike: ", longCall['Strike'], "is  ",longCall['Ask'])
            return i

def get_record_by_strike(strike, df ):
    print(df.loc[[strike]])

def main():
    # data frame
    df = read_csv_file()
    i = list_record_with_strike(510, df)
    get_record_by_strike(i, df)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but it really does not solve my problem, as still i have to go through the full DataFrame. i.e. we have the 510 row  when we invoke  ' "list_record_with_strike()" '  My question is about achieving "direct access" to one cell from which I know the floating unique key, and the column name...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I "RTFM" (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) and noticed that I had to explicitly say that I want to compare the value in the Column 'Strike' and that will give me the series.

Here is my new code:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/python

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import locale

locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8' )

def read_csv_file(pathToFile="options.csv"):
    return  pd.read_csv(pathToFile, header=2,
                              dtype={"Strike":np.float}, index_col="Strike",
                              usecols=["Strike","Bid","Ask","Bid.1","Ask.1"],
                              thousands=',').reset_index()


def list_record_with_strike(strike, df):
    for index, longCall in df.iterrows():
      if strike == np.float(longCall['Strike']) :
        print("Ask Price of strike: ", longCall['Strike'], "is ", longCall['Ask'])


def get_record_by_strike(strike, df ):
    series = df[df.Strike == strike]
    print("Ask price for strike: ", series.iat[0,0], " is " , series.iat[0,2])


def main():
    # data frame
    df = read_csv_file()

    get_record_by_strike(510.0,df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Observe that I get a Series by doing df[df.Strike == strike] which returns the full row with the data I want.
Then, I use iat[x,y] with x always = 0, and get the values of the specific column.

Please post if there is a more pythonic/pandonic way to do this.